# how to write php code of json array inside array based on id, so as not to increase

Tags: php, arrays, json

I want to try to create a `json array` that has an array inside that, but I have a failure where the result of the array in the array has issued the value looping in base `array`

this my php code

```
<?php 

require_once('include/db_connect.php');

$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM pesanan";

$response = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($response) > 0 ) {

    $result = array();
    $result['pesanan'] = array();

    while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($response)) {

        $h['id_pesanan']        = $data['id_pesanan'];
        $h['id_user']           = $data['id_alamat'];
        $h['id_beli']           = $data['id_beli'];
        $h['id_bank']           = $data['id_bank'];
        $h['kode_pesanan']      = $data['kode_pesanan'];
        $h['harga_pesanan']     = $data['harga_pesanan'];
        $h['harga_ongkir']      = $data['harga_ongkir'];
        $h['kurir_pengiriman']  = $data['kurir_pengiriman'];
        $h['status_pesanan']    = $data['status_pesanan'];
        $id_beli                = $data['id_beli'];

        $sql2= mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `keranjang` INNER JOIN `produk`
                                ON keranjang.`id_produk` = produk.`id_produk` WHERE id_beli='".$id_beli."'");

        while ($data2 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql2)) {
            $hs[] = array('nama_produk' => $data2['nama_produk'], 'spesifiksi' => $data2['spesifikasi_order']);

            foreach ($hs['produk'] as $data2['nama_produk']) ;

            $h["produk"] = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $hs)));

            $id_pesanan = $data2['id_pesanan'];
            $id_foto    = $data2['id_foto_produk'];

            $sql4 = "SELECT * FROM `produk_foto` WHERE id_foto_produk='".$id_foto."'";
             $response4 = mysqli_query($con,$sql4);
            while ($data4 = mysqli_fetch_array($response4)) {
                $h['foto_produk'] = $data4['foto_produk'];
            }
        }

        $sql3 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `pesanan_file` WHERE id_pesanan='".$id_pesanan."' ORDER BY nama_file DESC");

        while ($data3 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql3, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            $h['file'] = array('url_file' => $data3['url_file'], 'id_pesanan' =>  $data3['id_pesanan']);
        }

        array_push($result['pesanan'], $h);
     } 
     echo $result["success"] = "1";
     echo json_encode($result);

} else {

    echo $result["success"] = "0";
}?>`
```

output

```
> `{
    "pesanan": [
        {
            "id_pesanan": "49",
            "id_user": "39",
            "id_beli": "295023",
            "id_bank": "8",
            "kode_pesanan": "BRO-BZB9-160917-RMZB",
            "harga_pesanan": "866200",
            "harga_ongkir": "16000",
            "kurir_pengiriman": "J&T Express REG",
            "status_pesanan": "pending",
            "produk": [
                {
                    "nama_produk": "Kalender",
                    "spesifiksi": "Ukuran Cetak : Desk Calendar Horizontal\nSisi Cetak : Satu Sisi\nTipe Kertas : Digital Via Satin 216 gsm\nHalaman : 13 Pages\nLaminasi : Matte\nSpiral : White Spiral"
                },
                {
                    "nama_produk": "Flyer",
                    "spesifiksi": "Ukuran Cetak : A4  21 x 29.7 cm\nSisi Cetak : Dua Sisi\nTipe Kertas : Digital Via Satin 216 gsm"
                }
            ],
            "foto_produk": "http://192.168.43.245/broprint_api/adminweb/foto_produk/19082017025914flayer.jpg",
            "file": {
                "url_file": "http://192.168.43.245/broprint_api/upload/file/295035920Depan.jpg",
                "id_pesanan": "295035913"
            }
        },
        {
            "id_pesanan": "50",
            "id_user": "39",
            "id_beli": "29505",
            "id_bank": "17",
            "kode_pesanan": "BRO-5D1H-160917-DUGP",
            "harga_pesanan": "185000",
            "harga_ongkir": "15000",
            "kurir_pengiriman": "JNE Express OKE",
            "status_pesanan": "pending",
            "produk": [
                {
                    "nama_produk": "Kalender",
                    "spesifiksi": "Ukuran Cetak : Desk Calendar Horizontal\nSisi Cetak : Satu Sisi\nTipe Kertas : Digital Via Satin 216 gsm\nHalaman : 13 Pages\nLaminasi : Matte\nSpiral : White Spiral"
                },
                {
                    "nama_produk": "Flyer",
                    "spesifiksi": "Ukuran Cetak : A4  21 x 29.7 cm\nSisi Cetak : Dua Sisi\nTipe Kertas : Digital Via Satin 216 gsm"
                },
                {
                    "nama_produk": "Roll Up Banner",
                    "spesifiksi": "Ukuran Cetak : 85 x 200 cm\nSisi Cetak : Satu Sisi\nTipe Kertas : FF Korea 440 GSM"
                }
            ],
            "foto_produk": "http://192.168.43.245/broprint_api/adminweb/foto_produk/19082017043417ru4.jpg",
            "file": {
                "url_file": "http://192.168.43.245/broprint_api/upload/file/295036440.jpg",
                "id_pesanan": "295036420"
            }
        },
        {
            "id_pesanan": "51",
            "id_user": "39",
            "id_beli": "295019",
            "id_bank": "8",
            "kode_pesanan": "BRO-ZKFH-160917-IFH4",
            "harga_pesanan": "1125000",
            "harga_ongkir": "16000",
            "kurir_pengiriman": "J&T Express REG",
            "status_pesanan": "pending",
            "produk": [
                {
                    "nama_produk": "Kalender",
                    "spesifiksi": "Ukuran Cetak : Desk Calendar Horizontal\nSisi Cetak : Satu Sisi\nTipe Kertas : Digital Via Satin 216 gsm\nHalaman : 13 Pages\nLaminasi : Matte\nSpiral : White Spiral"
                },
                {
                    "nama_produk": "Flyer",
                    "spesifiksi": "Ukuran Cetak : A4  21 x 29.7 cm\nSisi Cetak : Dua Sisi\nTipe Kertas : Digital Via Satin 216 gsm"
                },
                {
                    "nama_produk": "Roll Up Banner",
                    "spesifiksi": "Ukuran Cetak : 85 x 200 cm\nSisi Cetak : Satu Sisi\nTipe Kertas : FF Korea 440 GSM"
                },
                {
                    "nama_produk": "Roll Up Banner",
                    "spesifiksi": "Ukuran Cetak : 60 x 160 cm\nSisi Cetak : Satu Sisi\nTipe Kertas : FF Korea 440 GSM"
                }
            ],
            "foto_produk": "http://192.168.43.245/broprint_api/adminweb/foto_produk/19082017043417ru4.jpg",
            "file": {
                "url_file": "http://192.168.43.245/broprint_api/upload/file/295036424.jpg",
                "id_pesanan": "295036433"
            }
        },
        {
            "id_pesanan": "52",
            "id_user": "39",
            "id_beli": "295030",
            "id_bank": "18",
            "kode_pesanan": "BRO-N844-160917-EFQB",
            "harga_pesanan": "200000",
            "harga_ongkir": "16000",
            "kurir_pengiriman": "J&T Express REG",
            "status_pesanan": "pending",
            "produk": [
                {
                    "nama_produk": "Kalender",
                    "spesifiksi": "Ukuran Cetak : Desk Calendar Horizontal\nSisi Cetak : Satu Sisi\nTipe Kertas : Digital Via Satin 216 gsm\nHalaman : 13 Pages\nLaminasi : Matte\nSpiral : White Spiral"
                },
                {
                    "nama_produk": "Flyer",
                    "spesifiksi": "Ukuran Cetak : A4  21 x 29.7 cm\nSisi Cetak : Dua Sisi\nTipe Kertas : Digital Via Satin 216 gsm"
                },
                {
                    "nama_produk": "Roll Up Banner",
                    "spesifiksi": "Ukuran Cetak : 85 x 200 cm\nSisi Cetak : Satu Sisi\nTipe Kertas : FF Korea 440 GSM"
                },
                {
                    "nama_produk": "Roll Up Banner",
                    "spesifiksi": "Ukuran Cetak : 60 x 160 cm\nSisi Cetak : Satu Sisi\nTipe Kertas : FF Korea 440 GSM"
                },
                {
                    "nama_produk": "Brosur",
                    "spesifiksi": "Ukuran Cetak : A4  21 x 29.7 cm\nSisi Cetak : Satu Sisi\nLipatan :  Bifold\nTipe Kertas : Art Paper 120 gsm"
                }
            ],
            "foto_produk": "http://192.168.43.245/broprint_api/adminweb/foto_produk/19082017024433br1.jpg",
            "file": {
                "url_file": "http://192.168.43.245/broprint_api/upload/file/295035830.pdf",
                "id_pesanan": "295035814"
            }
        },
        {
            "id_pesanan": "53",
            "id_user": "39",
            "id_beli": "295041",
            "id_bank": "8",
            "kode_pesanan": "BRO-Q7B6-160917-ZLSK",
            "harga_pesanan": "211000",
            "harga_ongkir": "16000",
            "kurir_pengiriman": "JNE Express REG",
            "status_pesanan": "pending",
            "produk": [
                {
                    "nama_produk": "Kalender",
                    "spesifiksi": "Ukuran Cetak : Desk Calendar Horizontal\nSisi Cetak : Satu Sisi\nTipe Kertas : Digital Via Satin 216 gsm\nHalaman : 13 Pages\nLaminasi : Matte\nSpiral : White Spiral"
                },
                {
                    "nama_produk": "Flyer",
                    "spesifiksi": "Ukuran Cetak : A4  21 x 29.7 cm\nSisi Cetak : Dua Sisi\nTipe Kertas : Digital Via Satin 216 gsm"
                },
                {
                    "nama_produk": "Roll Up Banner",
                    "spesifiksi": "Ukuran Cetak : 85 x 200 cm\nSisi Cetak : Satu Sisi\nTipe Kertas : FF Korea 440 GSM"
                },
                {
                    "nama_produk": "Roll Up Banner",
                    "spesifiksi": "Ukuran Cetak : 60 x 160 cm\nSisi Cetak : Satu Sisi\nTipe Kertas : FF Korea 440 GSM"
                },
                {
                    "nama_produk": "Brosur",
                    "spesifiksi": "Ukuran Cetak : A4  21 x 29.7 cm\nSisi Cetak : Satu Sisi\nLipatan :  Bifold\nTipe Kertas : Art Paper 120 gsm"
                },
                {
                    "nama_produk": "Kartu Nama",
                    "spesifiksi": "Ukuran Cetak : Standard 9 x 5.5 cm\nSisi Cetak : Satu Sisi\nLayout Cetak : Vertikal\nTipe Kertas : Art Carton 260 gsm\nTipe Sudut : Square corner\nLaminasi : Tidak Ada"
                },
                {
                    "nama_produk": "Kartu Ucapan",
                    "spesifiksi": "Ukuran Cetak : A5 14.8 x 21 cm\nSisi Cetak : Dua Sisi\nTipe Kertas : Art Carton 260 gsm\nLaminasi : Matte"
                }
            ],
            "foto_produk": "http://192.168.43.245/broprint_api/adminweb/foto_produk/19082017015653ku2.jpg",
            "file": {
                "url_file": "http://192.168.43.245/broprint_api/upload/file/295035413Belakang.jpg",
                "id_pesanan": "29503548"
            }
        }
    ],
    "success": "1" }`
```

help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: it's unclear what your problem is. What is wrong with the current output? What do you expect? Maybe give an example.

Comment: the array of `produk` in the `pesanan` has been repeated on the next `pesanan`, I want the `produk` that is only based on $id_beli @Jeff Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before every iteration of

```
while ($data2 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql2)) {
```

you need to clear `$hs` array:

```
$sql2= mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `keranjang` INNER JOIN `produk`
                            ON keranjang.`id_produk` = produk.`id_produk` WHERE id_beli='".$id_beli."'");

// Here set empty array
$hs = array();   

while ($data2 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql2)) {
    $hs[] = array('nama_produk' => $data2['nama_produk'], 'spesifiksi' => $data2['spesifikasi_order']);
```

Comment: how to order the output without "0" "1" and so on if more than 3 "pesanan": 
            "produk": {
                "0": {
                    "id_pesanan": "295035434"
                },
                "2": {
                    "id_pesanan": "295035312"
                },
                "4": {
                    "id_pesanan": "295035220"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "success": "1"
}

Comment: Please __do not__ ask questions not related to answer in comments. Ask __new question__ with detail problem description.